# Finding Word Stems in nltk python

Tags: nltk

! http://pik.vn/2015c740128e-11bc-40b0-8354-7fa58579d1d1.png

-i don't know [0] in the bove how it work

Comment: this code is [link]http://pik.vn/2015c740128e-11bc-40b0-8354-7fa58579d1d1.png

Comment: and result: >>> stem('ponds')
'pond'

Comment: Please repeat the code here and make your question more specific.

Comment: ! http://pik.vn/2015e0aa751f-39c8-4b80-8eb1-6a97a8212be8.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very vague, if you could call it a question at all.
But if you would drop the [0] after re.findall and throw in some print statements, you'll see that re.findall returns a list. The '[0]' after re.findall takes the first item of this list.

In addition; I'm not sure what you would want with re.findall in this case, since your regex specifies that the match should be surrounded by '^' and '$', so is probably not going to be more than one match, if any. I'm assuming you are feeding the stem function individual words then, in which case the ^ and $ are superfluous. 
Lastly; this type of stemming can be very fast and effective, but obviously it's pretty rudimentary: consider what would happen to "bus, blues, thing, lament", just to name a few.

Comment: thanks, i am so sorry about this topic. Because this is my first in this page. I will try to edit this. :'(

Comment: why when i input [1], it have wrong IndexError: list index out of range............ you can see this code ! http://pik.vn/2015e0aa751f-39c8-4b80-8eb1-6a97a8212be8.png

Comment: You get the IndexError because you try to access the second item in a list which only has one item. I'm not sure why you would want to design your stem function in this way at all. I may be overlooking things, but I'd go for something like "re.match(regexp, word).groups()[0]" instead of your re.findall line. And like yvespeirsman already noted; there is a very easy way of posting your code in here, instead of sharing it with a screenshot. Makes editing/answering your question a lot easier.